# has ailed vs. has been ailing

Tags: present-perfect, progressive-aspect

First off, take a look at these two examples please:

Example #1:

> This problem **has ailed** me for a long time.

Example #2:

> This problem **has been ailing** me for a long time.

Do you think you could confidently say that there really is a difference, however slight it might be though, in meaning between these two examples? Would you say that the first example gives the impression that the problem has troubled the speaker in the past for a long time, but does not trouble them anymore while in the second example the problem has been troubling the speaker for a long time in the past and most likely still continues to trouble them in the present?

Comment: This reminds me of a question discussed not long a time ago. I would agree with but some one told me that they mean the same thing when it comes to stative verbs.

Comment: Please stop using the "grammar" tag, it is meaningless, and used ubiquitously. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your sentences are correct and mean the ailment was in the past and continues

> This problem **has ailed me** for a long time.
>   This problem **has been ailing** me for a long time.

if the ailment stopped, it would be said

> This problem had been ailing me for a long time, *(but no longer does)*.

A possible different is degrees, as an analogy

> They **have been bothering** me for a long time.

sounds more annoyed, usually with emphasis on "been", than

> They **have bothered me** for a long time.

though both mean one has been and continues to be annoyed.